# Python simulation tree probability

Tags: python, simulation

I have to Write a simulation function that runs the game 100,000 times with the play_pig function expanded previously. View the percentage of simulation that ends with drawing a $ 5 bill.

At the annual fair, there is a game that uses piggy banks in the shape of a pig. In piggy bank # 1 there is a $ 5 bill and three $ 1 bills. In piggy bank # 2, there is a $ 5 bill and a $ 1 bill. To play the
game, you have to draw a bill from piggy bank # 1 and put it in piggy bank # 2. After mixing the contents of piggy bank # 2, you can take one of the bills. What is the chance of getting a $ 5 bill from piggy bank # 2?

```
class Expr:
  pass

class Times(Expr) :
  def __int__(self,l,r) :
    slf.l = l
    self.r= r
  def _str_(self) :
    return "(" + str(self.l) + "*" + str(self.r) + ")"
  def eval(self,env) :
    retunr slef.l.eval(env)*self.r.eval(env)

class Plus(Expr) :
  def __int__(self,l,r) :
    slf.l = l
    self.r= r
  def __str_(self) : 
    return "(" + str(self.l) + "*" + str(self.r) + ")"
  
  def eval(self,env) :
    retunr slef.l.eval(env)*self.r.eval(env)


Class Const(expr) :
def __int__(self,val) :
  self.val = val

  def __str__(self) :
    return_str(self, val)

def eval(self,env) :

Class var (expr) :
pass

print(e1)
(3*(x,y))
```

I just can't figure out the proper way to do it using python.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) This question is too broad.

Comment: I wish it was a homework it's for my personal curiosity im trying to solve my math problems while using python,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Analytic Solution

> B1 = bill pulled from piggy bank 1
> B2 = bill pulled from piggy bank 2
> P(B2 = 5) is the probability of pulling a 5 from piggy bank 2

#### Condition on the value of B1:

> P(B2 = 5|B1 = 1) = 1/3
> P(B2 = 5|B1 = 5) = 2/3

#### Solve for the unconditional probability:

> P(B2 = 5) = P(B2 = 5|B1 = 1) * P(B1 = 1) + P(B2 = 5|B1 = 5) * P(B1 = 5)
> P(B2 = 5) = (1/3) * (1/4) + (2/3) * (3/4) = 58.333%

Conceptually, you think of this like a probability tree. When you are working this out analytically, thats really helpful. But when you are coding something like this its really not what you want to do unless you are trying to write code that solves the problem analytically. Instead of writing code to replicate the math you need to write code that replicates the situation. You then run through the situation N times and **observe** the probability.

```
import random
import collections

piggy_bank_a = [5, 1, 1, 1]
piggy_bank_b = [5, 1]
outcomes = []
for experiment in range(100_000):
  bill_a = random.choice(piggy_bank_a)
  outcomes.append(random.choice(piggy_bank_b + [bill_a]))
totals = collections.Counter(outcomes)
```

Totals for me looked like this:

```
Counter({1: 58273, 5: 41727})
```

Comment: You're explication for making the difference between the mathematical point of view and the coding was really help full and clear!